# SUMIF after SUM exceeds certain amount?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet structured as follows:

```
quantity        | price | valid
1               | $5    | Y
4               | $7    | Y
2               | $5    | N
1               | $4    | N
1               | $6    | Y
1               | $5    | Y
1               | $5    | Y
1               | $4    | Y
1               | $5    | Y
1               | $6    | Y
```

I need to SUM the price for all rows after `ticket_quantity` exceeds 10, but `valid` needs to equal `Y` for the rows to count.

How would I best accomplish this?

Comment: Please also post desired output, just to avoid misunderstanding

Comment: Do you mean quantity*price > 10 and valid = Y, then output the result all quantity*price?

Answer (score 0):

In `E2`, enter array (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) formula  :

```
=SUM((ROW(A1:A10)>MATCH(10,SUMIF(OFFSET(A$1,,,ROW($1:$10),),"<>")+1))*(C2:C11="Y")*B2:B11)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. For Column D, Give the title in D1; " Cumulative Quantity "

   and F1 = " Sum of Price "
2. To begin with D2=1, ( Because A2 = 1 )
3. D3 = D2 + A3, Then Copy D3, Down the Column so D4=D3+A4, D5=D4+A5....etc.
4. Enter the formula in F2 as; F2 = SUMIFS($B$2:B2,$C$2:C2,"Y", $D$2:D2,">10")
5. Copy F2, down the Column to get desired results.

Thanks.